# refresh profile picture from twitter

Tags: php, image, twitter, profile

How can I include an option to use their twitter profile picture for the users instead of uploading new one for the profile.Is it possible to refresh the profile picture from twitter into my website account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a GET request to Twitter's servers using their API for retrieving the user's profile image.

Basically, by calling a GET request to an url like this:

```
GET: https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=twitterapi&size=bigger
```

it would return the image you want from the user on twitter.

Here's the API page for more details: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/%3Ascreen_name

Comment: please be careful, API v1 is deprecated.

Comment: ahh, my bad, totally forgot about the new upgrade to 1.1

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, all you have to do is to [connect to twitter's API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth) and access the following api path:

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show
```

The specific element you need is:

```
profile_image_url
```

After you get the result, you can:

1. Directly display the avatar image into your website
2. Download the image, and point the avatar to the saved image

Comment: see the link I gave you in the answer

Comment: don't read only that page, read the next page and page after that. As developer, you need to have the ability to read documentations.